# Insert string at the beginning of everyline of a text document?

Tags: string, insert, text-files

I am trying to insert a certain string with spaces "sBody = " before each line in a text document. I found this answer in other forums, but it does not work? A few questions I have about this script are, should "myfile" be the full filepath? Also, this script was originally made to insert a string at the end of the file, what do I need to take out to make it insert just one string at the beginning?

Thank you for all of your answers!

```
@echo off > newfile & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (myfile) do (
echo STRING %%a STRING >> newfile
)
```

Comment: You'd need to echo out your string to a new file, then append the original file to this new file, then replace the original with this new file. `>>` only appends, it won't prepend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is creating a new file named 'newfile' reading in the original file 'myfile'. Once it's done you can delete 'myfile' and rename 'newfile' to 'myfile' if you like. This example replaces each <line> in the file with STRING <line> STRING.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (myfile) do (
echo STRING %%a STRING >> newfile
)
```

Comment: How do change this to insert STRING at the beginning of each line without deleting the line? Are myfile and newfile the complete filepath? 

Thanks for the help

Comment: The angle brackets around 'line' got eaten in the original comment. (Now edited so they show proper.) To just prefix the line, you can instead use "echo STRING %%a >> newfile"

Comment: You're welcome. [I need to mind the eating of <tag>-like works in the answer text.]

Comment: I use this all the time, I now need to insert a & character and it is not taking it. Can I enclose in some brackets or something, because it is a special character?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine near me at the moment to check this but if I recall, you can escape a special character by putting a ^ in front of it. You _might_ need to make sure it's in a .cmd and not a .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*/pattern &/' yourfile.txt -i
```

works for me, in a single command line